# Swift - OSX application reveal with hotkey

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, swift2, xcode7

I'm building an OSX app using swift. I'm trying to reveal the app whenever hotkeys are pressed and hide it when the app loses focus. Kind of like how Spotlight Search (or Alfred) reveals whenever you hit `Command + Space`. How do I accomplish this behavior?

Comment: you can try addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask

Comment: Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see AXIsProcessTrusted).